# How to validate certificates?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, certificate

In firefox sessions without a tor proxy, it seems worthwhile to use an
extension that helps to validate SSL certificates (e.g. Perspectives or
Certificate Patrol). Is there any way to handle this problem with the
Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: // , .onion addresses don't need certificates, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can check manually, not as easy as a plugin/extension but...

Steve Gibson makes some handy tools for security, like this section-
https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm

Simply comparing a fingerprint from his server and your browser as being identical OR not, as he explains how, will validate if the CA is being spoofed and/or intercepted pretty quick.